# Hibernate lazy fetching

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have 3 Entities for example `Category`, `SubCategory`, and `Course`.
One category can have many subcategories and one sub-category can have many courses.
I have made one to many relations between category--subcategory and subcategory--course are made Fetch.Lazy.

```
class Category {
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "category")
    private Set<SubCategory> subCategories = new HashSet<>();
}

class SubCategory {
    @ManyToOne
    private Category category;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "subCategory")
    private Set<Course> courses = new HashSet<>();
}

class Course {
    @ManyToOne
    private SubCategory subCategory;
}

@Service
class CategoryService {
    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    public List<Category> findAll() {
        TypedQuery<Category> query =
            entityManager.createQuery("select c from Category c join fetch c.subCategories", Category.class);
        return query.getResultList();
    }
}

@RestController
@RequestMapping
class CategoryController {
    @Autowired
    private CategoryService categoryService;

    @GetMapping
    public List<Category> findAll() {
        return categoryService.findAll();
    }
}
```

Now when I fire a getAll Categories query with a fetch join sub-categories I get categories with sub-categories joined in the service but once the output is about to be given it is firing 'n' small queries to get courses and giving it to me as the output but I don't need it how to solve it?

Comment: Can you post the code?

Answer (score 0):

You can set a batch size on the courses associations, Hibernate will look for uninitialized collections and load up to 128 (for instance) at a time

```
class SubCategory {
    @ManyToOne
    private Category category;

    @BatchSize(size = 128)
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "subCategory")
    private Set<Course> courses = new HashSet<>();
}
```

Comment: When I hit the findAll Categories API it should load only the data which I get from the query in service but it is also giving me the courses because of lazy loading but I don't want it.
What I want is I should be able to control when the courses should be joined and when not.

Comment: Hopefully this article helps: https://thorben-janssen.com/dont-expose-entities-in-api/